# How to filter comma separated integer values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a varaiable in javascript like the following

```
  var element = parent.document.getElementById('productCollectionField');
  var values = element.value;
```

and an input field like

```
  <input type="hidden" value="1,2,3,4" id ="productCollectionField" />
```

so var element contains 1,2,3,4

Now I have value 5 and i want to check it in values .? How can i do that...? These numbers can be anything.

Comment: are you asking how to use String.split? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: will the values always be integers?

Comment: yes these values are always integer

Comment: **side note:** `parent.document.getElementById(...` is superfluous.  You can just use `document.getElementById(...`

Comment: actually this guy is within iframe..thats why parent.. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var myResults = values.split(",")
```

You will then have an array you can parse

Comment: you can use the jquery [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function or see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761975/parse-javascript-array

Comment: @SaurabhKumar this will put the values in an array so you can then use myResults[0] for the first value, myResults[1] for the second, etc.

Comment: actually i want something like which can iterate a array and check if the value is already present if it's already present then do nothin otherwise add to the array and then again merge back the array in comma seperated value.

Comment: @Surabh: you should edit your original question to be clearer. Where do you want to check if it's present?

Comment: @Saurabh: I think you would profit from reading a JavaScript tutorial to learn about basic language constructs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use the following function, which returns true of false whether the number is in the value string or not.

```
var value = '1,2,3,4';

function checkNumber(number, values) {
    var numberExists = false;
    var strArray = values.split(",")

    for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++)
    {
        // You could use if (strArray[i] == number), but using === is advised
        // since it's more specific about the type
        if ( parseInt(strArray[i]) === number)
            numberExists = true;
    }
    return numberExists;
}

// returns false
checkNumber(5, value);

// returns true
checkNumber(2, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is jQuery available to you? If yes, you can do it like this:

First, what JMax said:

```
var myResults = values.split(",")
```

Define the string that will be the output after the merge:

```
var newString = '';
```

Then,

```
if ( jQuery.inArray( 5, myResults ) == -1 ) {

    myResults.push( 5 );

    newString = myResults.join(',');
}
```

Cheers,